# How to send CLLocationCoordinate2D var to another file?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, geolocation

I'am new in obj-c and iOS programming.
So in one file/module i have written GPS+map, in this file/module I updating my geolocation.
In another file/module i have function witch take geolocation form first file/module as CLLocationCoordinate2D var. There is small code part witch explane what I mean.
**Someware in the GPS+map file is function:.**

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {
  if (AnotherModuleGeolocTaker!=nil) 
     [[AnotherModuleGeolocTaker getInstance] setLocation:[userLocation coordinate]];
...
```

**There is the geoloc. setter. In another file/module.h:.**

```
...
@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
...
```

**And in another file/module.m:.**

```
...
@synthesize location;
...
- (IBAction)ThereIsGeolocTakeAction:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"\n\nlatitude = %g\n\tlongitude = %g",location.latitude,location.longitude);
...
```

So how to send coordinates form 'didUpdateUserLocation' to 'ThereIsGeolocTakeAction' ?

Answer (score 0):

IBAction is used for hooking up a button in Interface Builder so when a user taps that button, it triggers a method call.  You don't want that here.  You just need a regular method.

In the map file, inside didUpdateUserLocation:   implement this code:

```
if (AnotherModuleGeolocTaker!=nil) {
    [[AnotherModuleGeolocTaker getInstance]
         ThereIsGeolocTakeAction:[userLocation coordinate]];
 }
```

In AnotherModuleGeolocTaker.m implement this method:

```
 -(void)ThereIsGeolocTakeAction:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)theNewLocation {
     NSLog(@"\n\nlatitude = %g\n\tlongitude = %g",
              theNewLocation.latitude,theNewLocation.longitude);
  }
```